# Use check_box to toggle between two elements in Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a dropbox that lets users select from several numerical values. However, I'd also like to give them the option to enter a custom numerical value, and toggling between these options with a checkbox.

In Android, you could do this with a Checkbox's onClick method, and toggle these other fields (the dropbox and the text field) to enabled or disabled. I'm a bit new at Rails development, and I was just wondering if something like this would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here dropbox mean dropdown ? 
You can do his by calling a JS function on checkbox click

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 to toggle between 2 different form elements.

```
.my-checkbox + input[type=range] {
  display: none;
}
.my-checkbox:checked + input[type=range] {
  display: inline;
}
```

The above CSS code will hide the `<input type="range">` element immediately after it, if only the checkbox with the class `my-checkbox` is checked.